# Query WMS for available layers using QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, wms

I believe we can do it using ArcGIS and I want to know if it is also possible, to query objects in a WMS layer using QGIS 3, my research so far have been unsuccessful. The identification tool does not work, nor the one for consulting the attribute table.

Comment: Some WMS layers may be queried, others not, it depends on what the providers allows.

Answer (score 3):

There is no attribute table for a WMS layer available in a client (QGIS or ArcGIS).  A query to a WMS layer is a query to the server providing the map (a GetFeatureInfo request) querying a point location (a pixel in the map image).  If the layer is queryable the server sends back a response for the attributes at that point in the underlying data.  Whether a layer is queryable in this way is discoverable from the GetCapabilities request to the service, through the queryable attribute on the layer.

Below layer is not queryable:

```
<Layer queryable="0" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
    <Name>BGS_625k_BAR</Name>
    <Title>GBR BGS 1:625k Bedrock Age</Title>
    <Abstract>GBR BGS 1:625k Bedrock Age</Abstract>
    <KeywordList>...
```

Below layer is queryable:

```
<Layer queryable="1" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
    <Name>GBR_BGS_625k_BLT</Name>
    <Title>GBR BGS 1:625k Bedrock Lithology</Title>
    <Abstract>GBR BGS 1:625k scale Bedrock Lithology</Abstract>
    <KeywordList>...
```